# change background-colour of clicked button in react:js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have some buttons when ever i click on a button i want it heighlighted by changing the background colur of the button until any other button is cliked

```
function clickedtime(e) {
   var time = e.target.value;
   settime(time);
  
 }
```

```
<TabPanel className="tabcss" style={styles.tabpannel}>
                 <button
                   onClick={clickedtime}
                   value="9:00am"
                   style={styles.button}
                 >
                   9:00am
                 </button>
                 <button
                   onClick={clickedtime}
                   value="9:30am"
                   style={styles.button}
                 >
                   9:30am
                 </button>

                ....


               </TabPanel>
```

Comment: Add a class to all the buttons and set appropriate background color for each of the elements of that class when click event happens.

Comment: @kiner_shah can u show a exmple

Comment: check out my answer if its solves your problem accept it. @meenu cd

Comment: What should happen after clicking on the button you're refreshing the page what should happen?

Answer (score 1):

Use event handler and useState for setting color onClick like this

```
const[btn,setBtn]=useState([0,0]);//mean two button

const[sel,setSel]=useState(0);//mean 0 button is selected by default
function clickedtime(e,index) {
var time = e.target.value;
 settime(time);
 setSel(index)//selected btn is 0in this case
}
```

now for your tab panel change style to style={{backgroundColor:col}} aslo change tabpanel styling like i  mention

```
<TabPanel className="tabcss" style={styles.tabpannel}>
           btn.map((item,index)=>{
           sel==index?

           <button
               onClick={(index)=>{clickedtime(index)}}
               value="9:00am"
               style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}
             >
               9:00am
             </button>
           :
             <button
               onClick={clickedtime}
               value="9:00am"
               style={{backgroundColor:"white"}}
             >
               9:00am
             </button>
             


             }  
            ....


           </TabPanel>
```

Comment: i tryed this but wheni click on any one button every button turns red

Comment: i edit the answer now check this out

Answer (score 0):

You can add all buttons to a class, add event listener to them and then have another class called "clicked" attached to them when the click event is fired.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("time-button");
var click_listener = function(event) {
  //console.log("clicked " + event.target);
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.remove("clicked");
  }
  event.target.classList.add("clicked");
};
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", click_listener, false);
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button class="time-button">9:30 am</button>
<button class="time-button">9:00 am</button>
<button class="time-button">8:30 am</button>
<button class="time-button">8:00 am</button>
```